# Differentiability of $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x) > 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and $f(x)^2$ is differentiable, is $f(x)$ necessarily differentiable? Can this simply be solved by using the definition of the product rule - that $(f(x)f(x))' = f(x) \cdot f'(x) + f(x) \cdot f'(x)$ and given the left side of the equation is guaranteed to exist, the derivative of $f$ is also guaranteed to exist?

Comment: not quite, since the expression $f'$ may not exist, so another route to prove this (or find a counterexample) is needed.

Comment: The product rule assumes that if $f, g$ are differentiable, then $fg$ is and it satisfies the product rule.

Answer (score 4):

The product rule doesn't come into this.

If $f$ and $g$ are differentiable and can be composed then $f \circ g$ is differentiable.

Here $f(x)>0$ for all $x$, and so $f(x) = \sqrt{f(x)^2}$ is the composite of two differentiable functions (since $t \mapsto \sqrt{t}$ is differentiable for $t>0$).

Comment: This is just terrific, and it explains how the counterexample in the previous answer. fails.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no restrictions on $f(x)$, then $f(x)$ need not be differentiable. See the following for a counterexample:

Well, $f(x) = |x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, but $[f(x)]^{2} = |x|^{2} = x^{2}$ is differentiable everywhere. Hence, by contradiction, $[f(x)]^{2}$ being differentiable does NOT imply $f(x)$ is as well.

However, if you give the proviso that $f(x)>0$ $\forall \; x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then by the other answer, it is indeed true. Thanks should go to Clive for noticing my mistake!

Comment: It's stipulated that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$, so your counterexample isn't valid.

Comment: I see your point. Will make change.

Comment: Yes...  misread question the second time around as well. Maybe I need new eyeglasses?